# Procedures in PLSQL using ORACLE DB

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ABC ( REG_NO   IN  CO_ENROLMENT.S_REGNO%TYPE,
                                  TERM     IN  COURSEOFFERING.CO_TERMNUMBER%TYPE,
                                  YEAR     IN  COURSEOFFERING.CO_YEAR%TYPE,
                                  CO_TITLE IN  COURSE.C_TITLE%TYPE,
                                  EN_DATE  OUT CO_ENROLMENT.COE_ENROLDATE%TYPE,
                                  COM_ST   OUT CO_ENROLMENT.COE_COMPLETIONSTATUS%TYPE)

AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT M.COE_COMPLETIONSTATUS, M.COE_ENROLDATE 
     INTO COM_ST, EN_DATE
     FROM COURSEOFFERING O
    INNER JOIN COURSE C
            ON C.C_ID = O.C_ID
    INNER JOIN CO_ENROLMENT M
            ON M.CO_ID = O.CO_ID
    WHERE M.S_REGNO LIKE REG_NO AND
          O.CO_TERMNUMBER LIKE TERM AND
          O.CO_YEAR LIKE YEAR AND
          C.C_TITLE LIKE CO_TITLE;
END ABC;
```

I have written down above procedure. 
Below is PL/SQL block to call above procedure,

```
DECLARE
  COMPL_STATUS   CO_ENROLMENT.COE_COMPLETIONSTATUS%TYPE;
  ENROL_DATE     CO_ENROLMENT.COE_ENROLDATE%TYPE;
BEGIN
  ABC (44444444, 2009, 2, 'PLSQL Programming', 
       EN_DATE => enrol_date, COM_ST =>compl_status);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('STUDENT COMPLETION STATUS AND ENROLMENT DATE IS ' 
                         || ENROL_DATE
                         || '    ' 
                         || compl_status );
END;
```

It returns me error as no data found, but when I run query separately I get the output. I couldn't figure out what is wrong. Did I wrote procedure block correctly and Parameters passed in PL/SQL block are correct?

Comment: if your procedure is not doing any insert/update/delete then why not use a function instead?

Comment: Everything is working fine except that output values are not printed......output line is printed i.e.STUDENT COMPLETION STATUS AND ENROLMENT DATE IS but no values for ENROL_DATE and COMPL_STATUS. I also cross checked with just query and it returned me output values with the same input parameters. I think the problem is somewhere in passing or retrieving output parameters though I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you passing the value 2009 to term and 2 to year? Surely these parameters should be reversed. It seems like you would benefit from always using named parameter notation (like you use for the last two parameters).

Comment: My above comment is true after making that correction!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling your stored procedure incorrectly. You have to specify parameters in the correct order, or use named parameter notation, ie

```
ABC (44444444, 2, 2009, 'PLSQL Programming', enrol_date, compl_status);
```

or

```
ABC (REG_NO => 44444444, YEAR => 2009, TERM => 2,
   CO_TITLE => 'PLSQL Programming', 
   EN_DATE => enrol_date, COM_ST =>compl_status);
```

You can see that if you use named parameter notation you can specify parameters in a different order (or not at all if the parameters have DEFAULT values).

Answer (score 1):

In proc you have year on third place buth you call it on second place. And how are types
(COURSEOFFERING.CO_TERMNUMBER%TYPE, COURSEOFFERING.CO_TERMNUMBER%TYPE) declared?

Comment: I declared all the field with the same type as that of a specified table's column.

Comment: Ind what about parameter switching

Comment: try declaring reg_no, term and year AS number type!

Comment: got the output as but date and completion status is not printed OUTPUT - STUDENT COMPLETION STATUS AND ENROLMENT DATE IS

Comment: then also change other parameter types in simple types (DATE, NUMBER, VARCHAR2...)

Comment: I think the problem is not with the type......I'm getting the output but without ENROL_DATE and COMPL_STATUS values. I get the values when I run the query separately with the same IN parameters.

Answer (score 1):

When `select` statement in your `ABC` procedure returns no rows the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception will be raised and execution of your stored-procedure will be halted. To avoid such behavior you need to add `EXCEPTION` section in the stored procedure to catch the exception and react appropriately. To that end the execution section of your stored procedure might look:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT M.COE_COMPLETIONSTATUS, M.COE_ENROLDATE 
     INTO COM_ST, EN_DATE
     FROM COURSEOFFERING O
    INNER JOIN COURSE C
            ON C.C_ID = O.C_ID
    INNER JOIN CO_ENROLMENT M
            ON M.CO_ID = O.CO_ID
    WHERE M.S_REGNO LIKE REG_NO AND
          O.CO_TERMNUMBER LIKE TERM AND
          O.CO_YEAR LIKE YEAR AND
          C.C_TITLE LIKE CO_TITLE;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found') -- for example
END ABC
```

Or if you want to proceed even if `select` statement raises exception you might enclose your `select` statement with nested `BEGIN .. END` block.

```
BEGIN
   -- some code before
   BEGIN    
     SELECT M.COE_COMPLETIONSTATUS, M.COE_ENROLDATE 
       INTO COM_ST, EN_DATE
       FROM COURSEOFFERING O
      INNER JOIN COURSE C
              ON C.C_ID = O.C_ID
      INNER JOIN CO_ENROLMENT M
              ON M.CO_ID = O.CO_ID
      WHERE M.S_REGNO LIKE REG_NO AND
            O.CO_TERMNUMBER LIKE TERM AND
            O.CO_YEAR LIKE YEAR AND
            C.C_TITLE LIKE CO_TITLE;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
     THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found') -- for example
  END;
  -- some code after
END ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably lack wildcards in your procedure query.

```
16:02:06 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> select * from dual where 'abc' like 'ab'; 

no rows selected                                                    


16:02:18 SYSTEM@dwh-prod> select * from dual where 'abc' like 'ab%';

D                                                                   
-                                                                   
X
```

Without them, `C.C_TITLE LIKE CO_TITLE` is equal to `C.C_TITLE = CO_TITLE`, which is not neccessarily what you want.

Try `C.C_TITLE LIKE '%'||CO_TITLE||'%'` etc.

Comment: Cool dude..........yippe...ohh man after so much of struggle finally got the output!!! Thank You so much wild card was the culprit.....but I had used TRIM function, it should had given me result?

Comment: maybe. maybe not. It depends upon what and how you were trimming. I can't tell without seeing actual code together with data.